# Assume P != NP, are these assertions valid?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, p-vs-np, polynomial-time-reductions

Assume $P \ne NP$, and $A$ is a problem in $P$ and $B$ is a problem which is $NP-complete$.
Are the following assertions valid?

1. $A \le_{P} B$
2. $B \le_{P} A$

**My approach**:

- $B \le_{P} A$ isn't valid, because if $B$ is reducible in poly-time to $A$, so $B$ has to be also in $P$. But thats not possible because $P \ne NP$.
- $A \le_{P} B$. Is it possible to reduce a problem in $P$ to a problem in $NP$ ? If it is, then the assertion is valid.

**Question:** Is my approch correct or am I missing some important point?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Regarding your second item: A problem in *P* is by definition in *NP*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. So this means that my B <= A isn't valid, but A <= B is valid, because all problems that lie in P are also in NP and so it is possible to reduce A to B in poly-time? So the first assertion isn't valid and the second assertion is valid?

Comment: In general, it is **not** possible to reduce a problem in $\mathsf{P}$  to a problem in $\mathsf{NP}$. However it is always possible to reduce a problem in $\mathsf{P}$ to a $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem.

Comment: This means that A is reducible to B, but B is not reducible to A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1: yes, since $B$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete it must be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, i.e., for every problem $C$ in $\mathsf{NP}$ we have $C \le_P B$. Since $A \in \mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$, we can pick $C=A$.

This is true regardless of whether $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.
Notice, however, that we are using the fact that $B$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. In general it is not possible to reduce an arbitrary problem in $\mathsf{P}$ to an arbitrary problem in $\mathsf{NP}$.

Regarding 2: no. Here your reasoning is correct, $B \le_p A$ would imply $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!  :)

Comment: While technically you are correct that $A\in \mathsf{P}$ does not $\leq_p$-reduce to an arbitrary problem in $\mathsf{NP}$, please note that it *does* reduce to any language in $\mathsf{NP}$ that is not $\emptyset$ or $\Sigma^\star$. In fact, $A\leq_p L$ for *any* $L\neq\emptyset,\Sigma^\star$. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172735/p-langauage-to-np-reduction-in-polynomial-time/3173210#3173210